# Establish Socket.io Connection before React Saga fires

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-redux, socket.io, redux-saga

I have a System that communicates between a node.js server and a react based frontend using websockets with socket.io. The sockets are a must as it's a collaborative tool and all users need to see the changes as they happen

The issue that is occuring is an odd one. We have a Redux-Saga set up that will trigger to fetch the data that the user should see, and is triggered within componentDidMount. This sometimes just doesn't happen. It would appear that when the page is first loaded all is fine, however when the user refreshes, the saga isn't triggered and so the data isn't retrieved.

This doesn't happen on Firefox, but is a real issue on Chrome unless you hard refresh the page. It would appear to be a timing issue, as it happens more often on faster connections. In the logs, I can see that when the issue does happen it would seem that the action is being dispatched, but  BEFORE the socket connection has actually been made. I'm guessing this is why it seems to be more of an issue for faster connections as the page is loading and dispatching the action faster than the connection can be made (though I could well be wrong on this)

### saga.js

```js
export const socket = io(socketServerURL);

export const connection = () => {
  const payload = {server:"CONNECTION_STARTING"};
  store.dispatch({type: "SERVER_CONNECTION_UPDATE", payload})

   
   return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    socket.on('connect', () => {
      resolve(socket);

      const payload = {server:"ok"};
      store.dispatch({type: "SERVER_CONNECTION_UPDATE", payload})
    });
    socket.on('connect_error', rsp => {
      const payload = {server:"CONNECTION_SERVER_ERROR"};
      store.dispatch({type: "SERVER_CONNECTION_UPDATE", payload})
    });  }); };

export const disconnect = (socket) => {

  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
      resolve(socket);
    });  });  };

export const reconnect = (socket) => {

  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    socket.on('reconnect', () => {
      resolve(socket);
    });  }); };

function* read(socket,room) {

  const channel = yield call(subscribe, socket, room);
  while (true) {
    let action = yield take(channel);
    yield put(action);
    //yield call(startConnection);
  } }

export function* subscribe(socket,room) {
  return new eventChannel(emit => {
    socket.on(room, rsp => {
      emit(serverUpdate(rsp));
    })
    return () => {}
  }) }

function* watcherForGetData(socket) {

yield takeEvery(constants.GET_DATA, (action) => {socket.emit('initial',action)});
}
const unrunFunctions= []
function* apiSaga() {
   yield all([
     fork(read, socket,'testPlan'),
     watcherForGetData(socket),
       ]) }

export default apiSaga;
```

Essentially, how can I make sure that the server connection is up and running before I try and use it to query data?